# Interpolation doens't work onInit, how can I make it work

Tags: angular, typescript

First, I have a component that subscribe the http get request from service and set the response to a variable. On service, I create a new Subject as observable so I'll be able to subscribe it in another component. But when I subscribe it on the new component, i'm able to get the object and also I can log it and it shows the correct value, but I can't display it in html by interpolation.

The service

```js
private transactionsToSend = new Subject<any>();
  currentTransactions = this.transactionsToSend.asObservable();

transactions() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this._url}/transactions`)
  }

sendTransactions(transaction: Transactions){
    this.transactionsToSend.next(transaction)
  }
```

The component that I subscribe it and send to another

```js
this.transactionsService.transactions().subscribe(
     (res : Transactions) => {
       this.transactions = res;

       this.transactionsService.sendTransactions(this.transactions);
     })
```

Then I get it on the another component

```js
  getReceives() {   
    this.transactionService.currentTransactions.subscribe(     
      (res : any) => {
        this.valueReceita = 0;
        this.currentTransactions = res.transactions;
        for (let x = 0; x < res.transactions.length; x++) {
          if (this.currentTransactions[x].chart == "+") {
            this.valueReceita += parseFloat(this.currentTransactions[x].value)
          }         
      }
      console.log(this.valueReceita)//This value is 99999
    })
  }
```

But when I try to display it

```js
<p>{{valueReceita | currency:'BRL'}}</p>
```

It doesn't show until I make another request

Comment: The answer is most probably in the question: first you call next() on the subject, *then* you subscribe to the subject in the other component. So the other component doesn't receive the first event, since it has been emitted before the subscription.

Comment: Thanks for helping, dude! But the reason for this problem is not this, J Rui Pinto is correct about it..

Comment: It is this. And using a BehaviorSubject solves the problem because a BehaviorSubject remembers and emits the last emitted value every time you subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace subject by BehaviourSubject

Comment: Thank you! Now I see that BehaviorSubject update data in real time.